# Get Direct Youtube Downlaod Link

Tags: hyperlink, youtube, manual

### How can I manually extract the Youtube Download Link?

e.g:

I have this link:   htps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fLexgOxsZu0

I want to get this: http://r9---sn-aigllnez.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?mm=31&sparams=id%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cmm%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cnh%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&mt=1411895530&id=o-AKzM1sExgAGdv0QN2N34ecTX7Vlwq-aee6o_sdj6Bg-k&expire=1411917209&upn=Et19mkCyt_U&fexp=927622%2C930666%2C931983%2C932404%2C934030%2C946023%2C947209%2C951912%2C952302%2C953801&nh=IgpwcjAyLmxocjE0KgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&key=yt5&ip=2a02%3A2498%3Ae000%3A85%3A225%3A90ff%3Afe67%3A97dc&itag=18&source=youtube&sver=3&mv=m&ratebypass=yes&initcwndbps=1296250&ms=au&ipbits=0&signature=7E977EA99135A34A09B780745FB4D4E7654160B2.F6234488D50CEFFFF741A7F30D0001034DD67D6D&title=Bruno+Mars+-+The+Lazy+Song+%5BOFFICIAL+VIDEO%5D

**How can I get the second Link?**

**What is the working Download Link above and what did I exactly extract below?**

***Thanks a lot in advace***

*Sorry for my bad english*

Comment: To Download videos you can use http://youtube.2tera.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will give you all download links in URL encoded form.

```
http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=VIDEO ID GOES HERE
```

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. I thought this thread was dead. Well thanks a lot for your answer. If I navigated to your Link I was promted to download a .bin file! Did I do something wrong? If not, is it possible to open the binary file?

Comment: open that file in notepad or any text editor you will see URL ENCODED information related to all that video. including download links. you can search url decoding sites where they allow u to decode it

Comment: @sulemanMuhammad this throws different results for the same video everytime how to fix this

Comment: it is changed from youtube side. you cant do anything about it. just call it one time and copy all urls from it.